# What's an easy way to access a directory of a docker volume with Nextcloud which is running in another docker container?

Tags: server, docker, ftp, nextcloud

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

My problems is as follows: I have a Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 with docker running on my home server.
On one **docker container** I'm running **Nextcloud** and on another container I'm running **paperless-ngx**. Now I would like to **access my scanned files from paperless via nextcloud**.

- So far I tried using **Proftpd** to add my Paperless-ngx archive directory via FTP as external storage to nextcloud.
  I think that this didn't work, because the docker volume isn't saved on my profile but instead in the system(?) files. So I couldn't access the directory with my profile login and also trying to login in as a root user didn't work either.
- Next, I tried to create a **soft/symbolic link** with `ln -s /<path to directory> /<path to directory>`. The link was working but I also couldnt create the external storage on nextcloud with Proftpd. I'm not entirely sure why it didn't work, but I think it's because the linked directory has the same root settings (which I was not able to change) as the original directory thus using FTP was not possible.
- Lastly, I tried using a soft link from my paperless directory directly to my nextcloud directory. I could see the directory in the terminal but it didn't show up, when I tried to access it in nextcloud.

I'm pretty new to using Ubuntu Servers and Docker containers so I probably made some silly decisions along the way.
Could I have done something different to get it to work?
Or are my "workarounds" not feasible at all?
If so: **Is there an easy solution to get this to work?**

Comment: Many containers include instructions for using bind mount volumes, such as [this Nextcloud container](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/nextcloud) by Linuxserver.io (notice the `volumes` section).

Comment: That sound very interesting, I'll take a look into that. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (for homelab use) is by using [Docker bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for persistent storage.

The official Nextcloud image even has a [section describing this](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/) (under Persistent Data).

An example of the command needed to run with persistent volumes for the config and data would be:

```
$ docker run -d \
    -p 8080:80 \
    -v /path/to/appdata:/var/www/html/config \
    -v /path/to/data:/var/www/html/data \
    nextcloud
```

Here, `/path/to/appdata` and `/path/to/data` need to be replaced with the actual full path of the folder where you want this persistent storage to be.

You could then map the folder `/path/to/data` into another container using the same method, allowing this folder to be directly shared between multiple containers and the host filesystem itself.